# Image.thumbnail() returns black image

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

I am trying to resize some photos that are too big to be processed by another script and it works on most pictures, but on some of them it only returns an 800x800 black image.

This is my code:

```
    from PIL import Image

    picture = Image.open(pictName)
    w, h = picture.size
    maxSize = 800
    if w > maxSize or h > maxSize:
        ratio = min(maxSize/float(w), maxSize/float(h))
        newSize = (w*ratio, h*ratio)
        picture.thumbnail(newSize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        os.remove(pictName)
        pictName = "../files/" + nameGen() + ".jpg"
        picture.save(pictName, "JPEG")
```

And this is one of the photos that don't work.

[image]

The photos have the same format (jpg) and are taken from the same source.

Comment: can you show your import statement, and a sample of the image that is causing the problem

Comment: Have you tried using the image.resize method instead ?

Comment: I did and got the same result, only slower, for some reason.

Comment: Now I did it "manually" and it worked as it should. Could there be some problem with the fact that I'm executing the script through CGI in Apache?

Comment: I just tried it (python 2.7.3, Ubuntu 10.04) - executed via the command line : and it works fine. I can't imagine what in the Apache/CGI environment would be problematic.

Comment: I am also wondering how could it work in the CLI, but won't work when executed by server. The fact that it only happens on some photos makes it even weirder. I hope I'll find a way to fix this.